# How to watch variable in a scope of controller which use several names in Angular

Tags: angularjs

All:

I wonder if I use a controller in template with `"as"`, but give it different alias in different places, I wonder how can I watch it?

Like:

```
app.controller("main", function(){
this.name = "hello";
})
```

And the template is like:

```
<div ng-controller="main as m1">
{{m1.name}}
</div>
<div ng-controller="main as m2">
{{m2.name}}
</div>
<div ng-controller="main as m3">
{{m3.name}}
</div>
```

**I wonder what should I use to be watched?**

```
$scope.$watch("m1.name", function(){});
$scope.$watch("m2.name", function(){});
$scope.$watch("m3.name", function(){});
```

Comment: where do you want to put this code? In the controller itself? Why not use `var that = this; $scope.$watch(function() { return that.name; }, ...);`

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, it works now, so if I use a function, the return value will be the actually one to compared, while if I use a string, it will first find the actually variable value accroding to that string and compare?

Comment: Almost: if you pass a string, angular considers it's an angular expression, and evaluates it on the scope, just like everything you put inside {{ }} in the template. So the string could be `foo + 3 - baz('bar')`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a watch function:

```
app.controller("main", function($scope){
     this.name = "hello";
     var vm = this;
     function watchFn() {
         return vm.name;
     });
     $scope.$watch(watchFn, function(newValue) {
         console.log("name="+newValue);
     }); 
})
```